# connection establishment between client and server

Tags: asp.net, tcp, connection, request, client-server

I want to know few basic things about **connection establishment between client and server**.
suppose my web page has left menu where i have some links, on click of those  child pages 
are open in the right side of master page .Now each link is requesting a new web page to 
the server. Each web page is calling 5-6 web services asynchronously to get the data. So 
if i am clicking on a left menu link, a connection is established between client and 
server using `(client IP and Port)` to `(server Ip and port)`. But before the response comes, 
suppose i clicked on other link of menu then how server knows that old conneciton is 
terminated and new connection is established.next thing,when i clicked on a link, request 
goes to server, server process the request but before sending the response if connection 
is terminated from client side, what happens to that response, does server discards the 
response and takes the new request for process.

actually i have lot of confusion, so if anyone can explain me the full client-server round trip process,that will really very helpful .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Server will discard the response and will work in subsequent requests. Reading about Hypertext Transfer Protocol will make you understand more. You can search on internet one of article is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

The request and response is made over TCP which is connection oriented protocol as the connection breaks IIS will know that client if not accessible. You try http://www.google.com.pk:80 will take you to http://www.google.com.pk as we can omit default port i.e. 80. Try this http://www.google.com.pk:82/ it will not open www.google.com as tcp connection could not be made on port 82.

Comment: but the question is how server knows about terminated connection.

Comment: When the server tries to write back the http stream to the socket, it will throw an exception because the socket no longer exists. The server will try to send the response headers first, and so will fail at this point. IIS manages this. Your asp.net code does not know if the socket has closed. However you can try response.write and response.flush to flush the response stream back out to the socket. Even doing this iis will have some response buffers that need to be filled first so it is not an accurate way.  As @Adil says you should read up about the http protocol, also iis internals.

Comment: The request and response is made over TCP which is connection oriented protocol as the connection breaks IIS will know that client if not accessible. You try http://www.google.com.pk:80 will take you to http://www.google.com.pk as we can omit default port i.e. 80. Try this http://www.google.com.pk:82/ it will not open www.google.com as tcp connection could not be made on port 82